# How I start specific methods with a object declaration?

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code :

```
function foo(){
    this.bar = {
        images: function() {
            this.example = "string";
            this.anotherFoo = true;
            (...)
            this.getBigPicturePositions = function(){};
            return this;
        },
        search: function(){
            this.thing = "string";
            this.anotherBar = false;
            (...)
            this.newAjaxSearch = function(){};
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I have this declaration :

```
var foo = new foo();
foo.start({
    bar: {
        images: {
            getBigPicturePositions: true
        },
        search: {
            newAjaxSearch: true,
            idontexist: true
        }
    }
});
```

How can I make a function like this who start the methods specified? I need this to start specific methods when i need to (if they exists of course). In my example, i need to get something like :

```
foo.bar.images().getBigPicturePositions();
foo.bar.search().newAjaxSearch();
```

Thank you for your help! I'm a newbie in javascript object.

---

**UPDATE :** The problem is solved with the solution presented by [CrazyTrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437417/crazy-train) but I have updated my code too. To view the result, please check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7D23/3/)

Comment: `this.bar: {` gives you a SyntaxError. What were you hoping `this` would represent here? If it's the object you're creating then just do `bar: {`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Hello, yeah I made an error, it's not a variable but a function. My original code has a function too here (instead of variable).

Comment: OK, trouble is that you're doing `foo.bar.images...`, but `this` inside the `foo` function is not a reference to the `foo` function. You seem to be trying to use code to express what you want, but you don't quite know how the code works, so it ends up not really communicating what you need. I don't understand the relationship between `foo`, `myObject`, the `this` object in `foo`, and the object you're passing to `myObject`. Could you please describe what you ultimately want to do?

Comment: ...I assume the object passed to `.start` is meant to be a series of flags to trigger `foo` methods, but I don't know how the objects are meant to line up.

Comment: I understand what you're doing. I'm sorry my English is poor but I'll try to get more clear : `myObject` is irrelevant. You need to consider this is just a object i've declared. And I need to start those methods if they exists in foo().

Comment: ...oh wait, you changed it again. Now you're overwriting the `foo` function with an object created from that function. Probably better to use a different name. But if `myObject` is irrelevant, how will the object you're passing to `myObject.start()` know about the `foo` *(or whatever)* object?

Comment: Yes i corrected my code sorry! In deed, `myObject.start()` is, a the end, a  method I need to create in `foo` to check the methods. I'm correcting this right now.

Comment: Ah OK, so ultimately the `.start()` method will be on the object whose methods need to be triggered. In that case, you're going to need to create a recursive function that accepts two objects. One object with the flags, and the other object with the methods. Then use `for-in` to enumerate the properties of the "flags" object, testing to see if each property holds a sub-object. If so, pass the sub-object from both objects in a new call to your function. If a boolean is found instead of a sub-object, then simply invoke the method on the object that has the methods.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yes, I think this is what i need! Can you make a answer with a sample code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, it's really pretty easy, but isn't obvious how to do it at first. I'll post an answer, but it'll just be a basic solution to use as a starting point to help you understand how to do it. From there it would be a good idea to just tinker around with it. Also, your `this` value in the nested functions may not be the value you expect, but that's another issue.

Comment: @CrazyTrain It's sounds good to me! Thank you!

Comment: I posted the solution, but there's another problem. Your `images` and `search` properties refer to functions but the `images:` and `search:` properties on the "flags" object gives no instruction to invoke them. Not sure how you want to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make the `.start()` method an inherited method for objects created from `new foo()`

```
foo.prototype.start = function(flags) {
    // call our recursive invoker function
    recursive_invoker(flags, this);
}
```

Then make a recursive function that iterates objects, and either recursively traverses nested objects when found, or invokes functions if a `true` value was given.

```
        // holds the flags---v     v---holds the methods
function recursive_invoker(flags, methods) {

    // enumerate the properties of the `flags` object
    for (var f in flags) {
        if (typeof flags[f] === "object" && typeof methods[f] === "object") {
            // objects were found, so make a recursive call with those objects
            recursive_invoker(flags[f], methods[f]);

        } else if (flags[f] === true && typeof methods[f] === "function") {
             // `true` was found, so invoke the function on the "methods" object
             methods[f]();

        } else {
            // Either we found `false`, or an object was not found, so do nothing.
            // This `else` isn't really needed.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! But the code is blocked with `images` and `search`. Your method need to pass that to call the methods inside. I'm trying in my side too.

Comment: @DrSAS: Yeah, I left a comment under your question about that. The methods inside aren't created until you invoke `images` and `search`, and then the value of `this` in the `images` and `search` method will depend on how that method is invoked. You seem to have something of an expectation for the value of `this` in a function to resolve to the function itself. It rarely does. In other words, the `images` property can't refer to the function and the objects the function creates at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, i dont know i this could be helping, but if you check the fiddle i've made, there is a variable called `self` to use the full scope in my method. But yes, if I understand, the problem is that `images` and `search` is a functions who need to be invoked to view inside. How can i resolve that?

Comment: To be honest, that's up to you. I don't know your ultimate requirements. I'm not sure why those are functions in the first place if you want them to be regular objects. Is there a reason why you can't just build the `images` and `search` objects immediately when you create the rest of it?

Comment: You're right. I made those methods to be enable to create some private variables. But if I need to do that, I can make the declarations inside the function who needed this. I update my fiddle. Your code is working great! Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/z7D23/3/

Comment: @DrSAS: You're welcome. And just as a side note, you can use the functions like you had, but simply invoke them immediately. So if you want them to create a new object, the you'd just do `images: new function() {...`. That'll invoke the anonymous function as a constructor, making `this` a reference to the new object that is automatically returned.